# I am not able to access data stored in ViewModel class

Tags: android, android-studio, model-view-controller, viewmodel

I am learning to use View Model in android and I couldn't access the variables I stored in my View Model class. For simplicity I created a new Project to try to implement a simple counter application, but here also I am facing the same issue.

I am not able to access my data in the View Model class from my UI controller.
Can anyone please help?

**My View Model**

```
package com.example.smish_hash20;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;

public class myViewModel extends ViewModel {
    int num = 0;
    void addNum(){
        num++;
    }
}
```

**Main Activity**

```
package com.example.smish_hash20;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int num = 0;
    ViewModel viewModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        final TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(myViewModel.class);

        textView.setText(String.valueOf(viewModel.num));

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                viewModel.addNum();
                textView.setText(String.valueOf(viewModel.num));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here Android Studio shows an error that num and addNum() are not recognized.

Comment: Try adding 'public' before the int and before void to make them accessible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared your view model as base type `ViewModel` meaning you will only be able to interact with the object as the base type after you initialize it (technically you could cast, but lets not go down that route).

You should replace this line :

`ViewModel viewModel;`

With your sub type :

`myViewModel viewModel;`

Making the method `addNum()` public is not neccessary - the default accessor is fine as both classes are in the same package.